# R - Adding group/condition variables to a time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have some biometric time series waveform data from different people, and have been using the zoo package to store the data. Toy example:

```
library(zoo)
w1 <- sin(seq(0,20,0.25))
w2 <- cos(seq(0,20,0.25))
df <- data.frame(w1,w1,w1,w2,w2,w2)
names(df) <- paste("waves", 1:6, sep="")
waves <- zoo(df)
```

But I also have a bunch of additional group/condition variables for each person (e.g., their age, gender, health condition). So imagine if I now need to do something with the waveforms of just the healthy people.

From what I understand, neither zoo nor xts objects accept additional variables. So my plan was to maintain a lookup dataframe for these additional variables. For example:

```
lookup <- data.frame(index = paste("waves", 1:6, sep=""),
                     group = c("healthy", "unhealthy"))
```

So now, if I need to sample the healthy people, I can do:

```
select <- waves[, lookup$index[lookup$group=="healthy"]]
```

Is there a better way or data structure to manage the time series + additional variables?

Comment: You can use a `data.table` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a **Panel Data** structure. Panel data, also known as cross-sectional time series data is data that varies across time as well as across entities. In your case, `value` of your `waves`'s vary across time within each entity whereas `group` varies across entities. We can do a simple `gather` and `join` to arrive a typical panel data format.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
panel_df = df %>%
  gather(index, value) %>%
  inner_join(lookup, by = "index") %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  mutate(time = 1:n())

#     index     value   group  time
#     <chr>     <dbl>   <chr> <int>
# 1  waves1 0.0000000 healthy     1
# 2  waves1 0.2474040 healthy     2
# 3  waves1 0.4794255 healthy     3
# 4  waves1 0.6816388 healthy     4
# 5  waves1 0.8414710 healthy     5
# 6  waves1 0.9489846 healthy     6
# 7  waves1 0.9974950 healthy     7
# 8  waves1 0.9839859 healthy     8
# 9  waves1 0.9092974 healthy     9
# 10 waves1 0.7780732 healthy    10
# # ... with 476 more rows
```

Here, `index` represents the entity dimension and I've manually created a `time` variable to indicate the time dimension of the panel data.

To visualize panel data, you can do something like the following with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Visualize all waves, grouped by health status
ggplot(panel_df, aes(x = time, y = value, group = index)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group))
```

[image]

```
# Only Healthy people
panel_df %>%
  filter(group == "healthy") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, color = index)) +
  geom_line()

# Compare healthy and unhealthy people's waves
panel_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, color = index)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(. ~ group)
```

[image]

Working with the time dimension:

```
# plot acf for each entity `value` time series
par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
by(panel_df$value, panel_df$index, function(x) acf(x))
```

[image]

```
library(forecast)
panel_df %>%
  filter(index == "waves1") %>%
  {autoplot(acf(.$value))}
```

[image]

Finally, the `plm` package is excellent for working with panel data. Various panel regression models from econometrics is implemented, but for the sake of not making this answer any longer, I will just leave some links for own research. `pdim` tells you the entity and time dimensions of your panel data and whether it is balanced:

```
library(plm)
# Check dimension of Panel
pdim(panel_df, index = c("index", "time"))
# Balanced Panel: n=6, T=81, N=486
```

1. [What is Panel Data?](https://www.thoughtco.com/panel-data-definition-in-economic-research-1147034)
2. [Getting Started in Fixed/Random Effects Models using R](https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101R.pdf)
3. [Regressions with Panel Data](https://rpubs.com/wsundstrom/t_panel)

I've modified your data for better demonstration.

**Data:**

```
library(zoo)
w1 <- sin(seq(0,20,0.25))
w2 <- cos(seq(0,20,0.25))
w3 = w1*2
w4 = w2*0.5
w5 = w1*w2
w6 = w2^2

df <- data.frame(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- paste("waves", 1:6, sep="")
waves <- zoo(df)

lookup <- data.frame(index = paste("waves", 1:6, sep=""),
                     group = c("healthy", "unhealthy"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the super detailed and helpful answer. I really appreciate it!